# Laravel Query Builder sum multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables as shown in the picture.
[image]

I would like to run a query that returns: Total_Parcel_Value, Total_Parcel_Delivery of **parcels** from all **orders** where **customer** = A.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your relationships are correctly setup, you could do this query:

```php
$res = Parcel::query()
    ->whereHas('order', function($q){
        $q->where('customer_id', 12);
    })
    ->selectRaw('SUM(parcel_value) as Total_Parcel_Value, SUM(delivery_fee) as Total_Parcel_Delivery')
    ->first();

$res->Total_Parcel_Value; 
$res->Total_Parcel_Delivery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

// Customer Model

```
...

public function orders(): HasMany
{
   return $this->hasMany(Order::class)
}
```

// Order model

```
...

public function customer(): BelongsTo
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class)
}

public function parcels(): HasMany
{
   return $this->hasMany(Parcel::class)
}
```

// Parcel Model

```
...

public function order(): BelongsTo
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Order::class)
}
```

Query:

```
Parcel::selectRaw('SUM(parcel_value)')
  ->selectRaw('SUM(delivery_fee)')
  ->whereHas('order.customer', function(Builder $builder) use ($customerName) {
     $builder->where('customers.name', $customerName)
   })->first()
```